# Problems occurring or occurring problems?

Tags: word-order, sentence-choice

> We should solve the problems occurring in this pandemic.
>
> We should solve the occurring problems in this pandemic.

Which sentences is grammatically correct and why it is?

Comment: Although some present participles can be used as the attributive adjective, "occurring" can not be used in that way. For example, *We should solve the growing problems associated with this pandemic* would work IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

The first.  This is because "occurring in this pandemic" is a phrase that modifies the noun as a whole.